# SystemParametersInfo SPI_GETNONCLIENTMETRICS.lfMessageFont how to make consistant for scaling?

Tags: winapi, scaling, dpi

Using PerMonitor DPI Aware and PerMonitorV2 DPI Aware win32 app running on Win10 1909 I find an issue with generic font scaling using a DPI helper.   Using `SystemParametersInfo()` with `SPI_GETNONCLIENTMETRICS` returns based on a DPI at the time the app was started.   If I start the app when at 150DPI, the lfHeight is -18, If I start up at 96DPI, the lfHeight is -12, but when WM_DPICHANGED is called on changing from 96DPI to 150DPI, it's still -12.  So that means the value depends on the DPI when the app was started.   That causes an issue with generic scaling since if starting at 150DPI and moving to 200DPI it will be -36 instead of -24.  So is it expected/true that you have to save the startup DPI and use that when determining how to scale the font returned by the `SystemParametersInfo()`

TIA!!

Comment: The `HIWORD` or the `LOWORD`  of the `wParam` contains the value of the new dpi of the window. Refer to [`WM_DPICHANGED` message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/wm-dpichanged).

Comment: Doesn't look like anyone read what I actually wrote?   It's specific to the SPI_GETNONCLIENTMETRICS data.

Comment: It looks like that is the case, I had to add a new scale factor specific for those fonts based on DPI at startup.   Now I find issue with Window in Win10 when starting at a higher DPI and move to a smaller one, windows has a border around the client area (flashes some times until clicked in and out.  I'll start new question.

Comment: @df234987 Do you mind sharing the reason that you use `SystemParametersInfo` instead of `WM_DPICHANGED`?

Comment: it's for scaling the font as part of WM_DPICHANGED

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I start the app when at 150DPI, the lfHeight is -18, If I start up
>   at 96DPI, the lfHeight is -12, but when WM_DPICHANGED is called on
>   changing from 96DPI to 150DPI, it's still -12.

*[`SystemParametersInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-systemparametersinfoa#remarks) API is not DPI aware, and should not be used if the calling thread is per-monitor DPI aware. For the DPI-aware version of this API, see [`SystemParametersInfoForDPI`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-systemparametersinfofordpi).*

The `SystemParametersInfoForDpi` API gives expected result for me you can try it like this:

```
case WM_DPICHANGED:
{
    WORD newDpi = HIWORD(wParam);

    NONCLIENTMETRICS info = { 0 };
    info.cbSize = sizeof(info);

    if (!SystemParametersInfoForDpi(SPI_GETNONCLIENTMETRICS, sizeof(info), &info, 0, newDpi))
        err = GetLastError();
}
```

Comment: IMPORTANT: If you dynamically load SystemParametersInfoForDpi() from User32.dll and it returns ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER this may be because you use an older version of Visual Studio to write software compatible with older Windows versions. The size of NONCLIENTMETRICS  MUST be 504 otherwise you get an error!